# Start R Shiny app as a background job programmatically

Tags: r, shiny, background-process

Dean Attali has provided a wonderful example on [how to exit elegantly](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/close-window/app.R) from a Shiny app using a close button which both closes the browser window and ends the Shiny session. Consider the following example (modification of the original code from Dean):

The `ui.r`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "shinyjs.closeWindow = function() { window.close(); }"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("closeWindow")),
  htmlOutput(outputId = "exitHeading"),
  actionButton(inputId = "closeGUI", label = "Exit")
)
```

The `server.r`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$exitHeading <- renderText("Press the button below to exit the app")
  observeEvent(input$closeGUI, {
    js$closeWindow()
    stopApp()
  })
}
```

And running the app:

```
runApp(appDir = "/tmp")
```

My question is about how to start a Shiny app as a background job **programmatically**, so that the RStudio console is free for further use (or even start a second Shiny app in parallel) while the app is still running, and then end the job using the exit button from the app above. I am looking for a solution which can be added to a package which contains a Shiny app, [like this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CTTShiny/index.html).

I have read [this](https://github.com/sol-eng/background-jobs/tree/master/shiny-job) and have tried the provided sample app, but it still requires manual intervention by the user.

Can someone assist with this?

Comment: There is a way of turning a shiny app in to its own executable program, using this github package [RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno). I had mixed success with it in that it worked on my computer but I struggled to share it with others who didn't have R. There probably is a way but I was only looking at it for fun

Comment: @Jonny Phelps: Thank you. This is good to know.

Comment: I think the way to run a shinyApp as a background job would be to use system and call `Rscript file.r` i.e `system('Rscript file.r', wait=F, show.output.on.console = F)`

Comment: @Abdessabour Mtk: Thank you! However, this needs to point to a specific R code file. How would this work within a package?

Comment: @panman I think you can use the {callr} package to run the shiny app as a background job in RStudio (and it should appear in the jobs panel).

Answer (score 1):

OK, fast forward to more than 2.5 years after making the original post, I found the solution. I have tried different options suggested here and in general on the web. Nothing worked. I tried using `callr`, as suggested by Vlad. [This post](https://wlandau.github.io/posts/2020-12-18-non-blocking-app/) provides a good overview and solution, but I never managed to make it work in a package, as I wanted. When the browser window opens, I always get "Not found". In addition, I always had to define which browser it has to start in, but there is no way to know if the user would have exactly this browser on the system (nowadays browsers are galore).

The solution I finally got to work is using the [`rstudioapi`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstudioapi) package which has utilities for starting and managing background jobs.

**I. First, the solution I got to work by just using a shiny app outside of a package, i.e. somewhere on your hard drive as `ui.r` and `server.r` files.**

I use the `ui.r` and `server.r` from the original question, put together in a folder.

Load the libraries:

```
library(shiny)
library(rstudioapi)
```

Create a file `guiscript.r` (or name it as you wish) with the following content:

```
myGUI <- function() {
  appDir <- "<path to the folder containing the ui.r and server.r files>"
  shiny::runApp(appDir = appDir, display.mode = "normal", quiet = TRUE, host = "127.0.0.1", port = 3838)
}
myGUI()
```

Run the `guiscript.r`, but not using the usual `source()` function, use the `rstudioapi::jobRunScript()` for doing this:

```
eval(parse(text = 'invisible(rstudioapi::jobRunScript(path = "<path to the folder containing the ui.r and server.r files>/guiscript.r",
     importEnv = TRUE, exportEnv = "R_GlobalEnv"));browseURL(url = "http://127.0.0.1:3838");rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "activateConsole")'))
```

Note there are multiple R commands chained together in the statement divided with `;`. The last one (`rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "activateConsole")` switches back from the `Background jobs` panel to the console in Rstudio.

When executed, the above starts a background job, invokes the browser and loads the app. Then it switches back to the console which is now free, exactly what I was aiming for.

NOTE: When started, you may see "Not found" in your browser for a second or two because it takes some time before starting to render. In this case, add a `Sys.sleep(1)` (or higher value) before the `browserURL()` statement.

**II. Second, use this in a package.**

Use the regular practice to create `/inst/shiny/GUI/` folder in your package directory and put the `ui.r` and `server.r`, similar to what Dean Attali suggests [here](https://deanattali.com/2015/04/21/r-package-shiny-app/).

In `/inst/shiny/GUI/` where you have already placed your `ui.r` and `server.r` add an file `startGUI.r` (or name it as you would prefer) with the following content:

```
appDir <- system.file("shiny", "GUI", package = "<mypackagename>")
if (appDir == "") {
  stop("Could not find the app directory. Try re-installing `<mypackagename>`.", call. = FALSE)
}
shiny::runApp(appDir = appDir, display.mode = "normal", quiet = TRUE, host = "127.0.0.1", port = 3838)
```

Finally, in the `/R` folder in the package directory structure add the following file `packageGUI.r` (or name it as you would prefer):

```
#' @title Start the GUI
#'
#' @description Starts the GUI.
#' @export

packageGUI <- function() {
  path.to.start.GUI <- system.file("shiny", "GUI", "startGUI.r", package = "<mypackagename>")
  eval(parse(text = paste0('invisible(rstudioapi::jobRunScript(path = "', path.to.start.GUI,'", importEnv = TRUE, exportEnv = "R_GlobalEnv", name = "Any name you choose the job shall be called"))')))
  Sys.sleep(1)
  browseURL(url = "http://127.0.0.1:3838")
  rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "activateConsole")
```

Note the `Sys.sleep(1)`, this is to avoid seeing "Not found" in your browser for a moment after the function is called.

After you load the library, just call the `packageGUI` function.

It works now. The shiny app is started as a background job, all messages are redirected to the job's pane and the console is free. I'm finally happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

So as I mentioned in the comments you can achieve this by using the `system` which basically runs a terminal command, with the `wait` and `show.output.on.console` flags set to `FALSE`.

```r
system('Rscript file.r', wait=F, show.output.on.console = F)
# if you want to access a file from in a package u need
# also in the source of the package you need to put the
# folder `directory` in `root.of.package/inst`
p <- system.file(file.path("directory", "myfile.r"), package = "my.package")
system(paste0('Rscript "', p, '"'), wait=F)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you, will try later and let you know.

Comment: `p` is constructed, but pointing to the folder where the R project for producing the package is. Later, when `devtools::check()` tests whether the package can be installed it drops an error that a file path is hard coded: `ERROR: hard-coded installation path: please report to the package maintainer and use ‘--no-staged-install’`. I checked the log, it really creates a path where the package project is created.

Comment: use `remove.packages(devtools::as.package("."))` then retry.